# Changing a for into a foreach loop

Tags: php, for-loop, foreach

You know, I may be totally off...After further review, it seems more like I should be looking into php mail headers instead...I was trying to do a fo each loop for each $count they input to send a different email header, although it may have to do with the headers instead. I am trying to get the $randomNumber to show up as a different number for each email they receive, which the quantity will be determined on the $count variable that they input. What it is doing now is, say they chose 3 as the $count input, it would send 3 emails with the same From: 15158451@theirdomain.com instead of each email with a different random number..Anyway you know to solve this? thank you

```
<input name="count" id="count" maxlength="2" />


$count                    = $_POST['count'];
$randomNumber             = rand();

if (isset($_POST['randomizeEmail'])) {

    for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
{
        $headers = "From: $randomNumber@$customerDomain\r\n";
        $body    = $message;
        $email   = $customer. "@" . $provider;
        (mail($email, $subject, $body, $headers));
```

Comment: One *could* use [`range()`](http://php.net/range). But using a `foreach` doesn't make sense for this.

Comment: Why do you really need a foreach loop in your case? can you explain?

Comment: This is a part of a form, that the $count variable is input in by the user, it then sends the generated 9-10 digit number as many times as the $count input was set to. However, I would like a different random number per $count, which it is not doing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Mario suggested you shall use [range](http://php.net/range)

```
<?php
#0 and 12 respresentes your start and end i.e., your $i and $count
foreach (range(0, 12) as $number) {
    echo $number;
}
?>
```

But the [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) is mostly used to iterate over arrays which you may not require in your case.

**Note :**

[foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) works only on arrays and objects, and will issue an error when you try to use it on a variable with a different data type or an uninitialized variable.

```
$count  = $_POST['count'];
$randomNumber = rand();
if (isset($_POST['randomizeEmail'])) 
{
#Your Mail Code here
}
```

**Update :** (As the user wants to know how to generate random number in each header)

Then you should have the `$randomNumber = rand();` inside the `for` loop

i.e.,

```
 for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) 
{
$randomNumber = rand();  # randomnumber is generated every time here ;)
$headers = "From: $randomNumber@$customerDomain\r\n";
}
```

Comment: when the form is submitted with the $count input filled in by the user, it is only generating one random number. I would like to have it generate a new number for each $count, going by the number that was put in. If I entered say 6 on the forum, in the count input. I would like the form to submit 6 randoms numbers like my for loop was doing, except it would only do one

Comment: I am not clear little bit, You mean to say It will create the random number from the users input ?

Comment: Thank you. Sorry for the confusion, I have updated the main post. Can you please take a look when you get a chance..I appreciate the help

Comment: For each email you need to send different random as email header ? i.e., `15158451@theirdomain.com`  in first mail, `34563489@theirdomain.com` in second mail like that ?

Comment: Yes exactly, I am only able to get it to send all email's they choose to one random header

Comment: Then you should have your `$randomNumber = rand();`  inside your for loop, i have updated it in my answer

Comment: Oh my, don't know how I missed that, but you saved my headache. Thank you!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74681/discussion-between-kjthadon-and-sulthan-allaudeen).

Answer (score 1):

$count may you have total number of post but real posted values. So try like this.

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
    //your rest code..
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example, its easy.

```
<?php
$arr = array(1, 2, 3, 4);
foreach ($arr as &$value) {
    $value = $value * 2;
}
// $arr is now array(2, 4, 6, 8)
unset($value); // break the reference with the last element
?>
```

The foreach construct provides an easy way to iterate over arrays. foreach works only on arrays and objects. more: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php